# typescript - class validator - validate based on different type

Tags: typescript, typeorm, class-validator

I'm working with TypeORM, and I would like to provide different to field based on other field value. So to explain, here is how my DTO model looks:

```
import { IsString, IsOptional, IsNumber, IsEnum, IsObject, IsBoolean, ValidateNested } from 'class-validator';

export enum AttributeTypes {
    DATE = 'DATE',
    TIME = 'TIME',
    NUMBERS = 'NUMBERS',
}

export class BaseValidation {
    @IsOptional()
    @IsBoolean()
    required: boolean;
}

export class modelCreate {
    @IsOptional()
    @IsNumber()
    id: number;

    @IsOptional()
    @IsString()
    label: string;

    @IsOptional()
    @IsEnum(AttributeTypes)
    type: AttributeTypes;

    @IsOptional()
    @IsObject()
    @ValidateNested()
    validation: BaseValidation;
}
```

The problem here is that I have this field: **validation** in modelCreate, & that field is an object and can have multiple properties & can look like this in db:

```
validation: {
   required: true,
   text: 2
}
```

or it can look like this:

```
   validation: {
       required: false,
       number: 1,
       maxNumber: 10
    }
```

and that would depend on **type** property of modelCreate, because if type is 'TIME', I would like to have validation for this:

```
BaseValidation {
    @IsBoolean()
     required: true,
    @IsString()
    text: 2
}
```

and if type is 'NUMBERS', I would like to have validation like this

```
  BaseValidation {
           @IsBoolean()
           required: boolean,
           @IsNumber()
           number: number,
           @IsNumber()
           maxNumber: number
        }
```

So the question is how would I toogle different classes in validation field based on type field value in class validator, and is that even possible ?

Answer (score 3):

for that you need to create 2 classes, for every case, string and numbers.
Then change the type `validation: StringBaseValidation | NumberBaseValidation;` now class-validator can distinguish the cases.

If the data comes from a request you need to use `@Type((obj) => obj.writeConditionToDetectString ? StringBaseValidation : NumberBaseValidation)` to help the lib to understand which type is the data from the request.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a discriminative field, to allow the class-transformer to identify the type to cast and use in the validation. The same can be done with nested array objects. In your case you can use the "required" field

In the example below, if the property `required` is equal to `true`, then we use the class `A`, in the other hand, if the property `required` is equal to `false`  the class to be used is `B`.

In the `discriminator` property you should set a field to be used to identify the different polymorphic forms of the nested objects. The `subTypes.[].value` is the class to be used in validation and `subTypes.[].name` is the value that the `discriminator` field should have to assume the class added in the `subTypes.[].name` field.

```js
import { Type } from 'class-transformer';
import { IsBoolean, IsNumber, IsString, ValidateNested } from 'class-validator';

class Discriminator {
  @IsBoolean()
  required: boolean;
}

class A extends Discriminator {  
  @IsString()
  text: string;
}

class B extends Discriminator {  
  @IsNumber()
  number: number;

  @IsNumber()
  maxNumber: number
}

export class C {

  // Other fields...

  @ValidateNested()
  @Type(() => Discriminator, {
    discriminator: {
      property: 'required',
      subTypes: [
        { value: A, name: true as unknown as string },
        { value: B, name: false  as unknown as string },
      ],
    },
    keepDiscriminatorProperty: true,
  })
  validation: A | B;
}
```

Now your controller should look like this:

```js
@Controller()
export class AppController {
  @Post()
  public example(
    @Body(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true }))
    body: C,
  ) {
    return body;
  }
}
```

And you can do your requests:

```bash
curl --location 'localhost:3000/' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
  "validation": {
    "required": true,
    "text": "Some text..."
  } 
}'
```

If you change the second element of the `required` property to false, then you will see an error:

```
{
- "required": true,
+ "required": false,
  "text": "Some text..."
}
```

```json
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "message": [
    "validation.number must be a number conforming to the specified constraints",
    "validation.maxNumber must be a number conforming to the specified constraints"
  ],
  "error": "Bad Request"
}
```

---

> **References**:
> https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer#providing-more-than-one-type-option

Comment: The workaround of the type is mentioned here: https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer/issues/737